# error: no matching function for call to with constructor initialization

Tags: c++, constructor

d.cpp file:

```
#include "file.hpp"

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
        ns::T t ("ssssss");
}
```

file.hpp

```
using namespace std;


namespace ns{

    struct T{

        T(string s);

    };
    };
```

Why do I get this errors?:

> file.hpp:8:20: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘s’    T(string s);
>
> d.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: d.cpp:14:26: error: no matching
>   function for call to ‘ns::T::T(const char [6])’    ns::T t ("ssssss");
>   In file included from d.cpp:8: file.hpp:6:12: note: candidate:
>   ‘constexpr ns::T::T()’ struct T{

Comment: Where's your `#include <string>`?

Comment: Whenever you have an issue with such small files, instead of using `#include` just copy paste the code and let your IDE auto-format it for you, 100% you'll instantly see the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include "string":

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;

namespace ns{

  struct T{
      T(string s);
  };
}
```

Comment: ... and there is a `}` missing at the end of file.hpp

Comment: added string include and closing bracket, but now I got new error "undefined reference to `ns::T::T(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)'"

Comment: @Sergey What does your file.cpp look like? Did you implement the constructor of `T`?

Comment: @SergeyArenzon you need to _implement_ `T::T(string)`. So far you only _declared_ it.